# Pygame: Whenever I try to pick up a tile that I have already thrown, I get an error

Tags: pygame

I was making a game with pygame where you could pick up tiles and throw them. I ran into an issue where if I threw a block and tried to pick it back up, I get an error. I know what the issue is, but I don't know how to fix it

IndexError: pop index out of range
This gets the index of the block that I am going to pick up:

```
# Checks if player is touching a block and pressing down arrow to remove a block and add a block above the player's head
    if collisions["left"] and pick_block or collisions["right"] and  pick_block:
        for tile in xcollisions:
            if pick_block_count == 0:
                if not holding_block:
                    tpb = tile
                    tile_pops.append(tile_rects.index(tile))
                    holding_block = True
                    pick_block_count += 1
    else:
        xcollisions = 0
```

```
# Removes the tile that is picked up
    for tile in tile_pops:
        tile_rects.pop(tile)
        drectp = display_rects.pop(tile)
```

That removes the block. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it

Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/3eszkgkK
Here is the map I use: https://pastebin.com/ftWL4mVD
For the textures you can use any 16x16 texture

Comment: Can you please explain what your code is trying to achieve in the second code-section.  The description reads like it's dealing with a single tile, yet it's looping over a list of tiles.  Why is it passing the `tile` (index?) , e.g.: `pop( tile )` ?   Could you just not use `pop()` ?  Once you remove an element from `tile_pops` it's length, and the all the item indices will change.  So remove them in revere order, always remove the first, or re-work the algorithm.

Comment: The first one gets the index of the tile that needs to be removed and the second one pops the tile from the list using the index. It needs to loop because if there are multiple tiles that need to be removed, it will remove all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my code. The issue wasn't because as the list shrinks, the index to remove doesn't shrink with it, but it was what I originally stated. I had to pop the tile from the thrown_drect list and pop the tile from tile_pops. Here is what I am trying to explain:

```
# If the tile that is being popped has been thrown before, it pops it from thrown_drect (or else it would cause an error)
    if ttpop:
        print(abs((len(tile_rects)-tile_pops[-1]) - len(thrown_drect)))
        tpopped_value = thrown_drect.pop(abs((len(tile_rects)-tile_pops[-1]) - len(thrown_drect)))
        tile_pops.pop(-1)
    # Removes the tile that is picked up
    for tile in tile_pops:
        tile_rects.pop(tile)
        drectp = display_rects.pop(tile)
    if ttpop:
        print("yes")
        drectp = tpopped_value
        print(drectp[0])
        ttpop = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this piece of code:

```
fruits = [ 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian' ]

for i in range( len( fruits ) ):
   print( "i == %d" % ( i ) )
   fruits.pop( i )
   print( "-------------------------" )
   print( "fruits now: "+str( fruits ) )
```

It fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bad_pop.py", line 5, in <module>
    fruits.pop( i )
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

This is because on the first iteration of the loop, it removes `fruits[0]`.  That's fine.  Then `fruits[1]`.  But then on the third pass, the list is only *two* elements long - `0` and `1`, but `i` is `2`!  It's out of range.

This is what's happening with your `pop()`, as the list shrinks, your index to remove doesn't shrink with it.

```
remove fruits[0] - [apple]
fruits now: ['banana', 'cherry', 'durian']
-------------------------
remove fruits[1] - [cherry]
fruits now: ['banana', 'durian']
-------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bad_pop.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = fruits.pop( i )
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

So what can you do.  Re-work your loop so that it only ever uses `pop()` to take the 0th element.  Or loop from `len( list )` down to `0`, so the shrinking-size of the list does not matter.

EDIT:
Maybe something like:

```
tile_pops.sort()
tile_pops.reverse()
for tile in tile_pops:
    tile_rects.pop(tile)
    drectp = display_rects.pop(tile)
```

But that's a fairly computationally-expensive way of doing it.

Comment: How would do that?

Comment: I tried that out but it still doesn't work. I don't really know how to describe it. Did you look at my pastebin link?

Comment: @User-92 - Yeah, but I don't have a map to run it.

Comment: I added the map